# how to bind click event from ts to html dynamically to anchor tag using inner html in angular 7?

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, anchor, sanitization

I want to bind click event from ts to html dynamically to anchor tag.
Ts file:

```
 this.RecommendedTests.Description = '<a (click)="showModel()">' 
  +this.RecommendedTests[i].Description + '</a>';
```

html:

```
 <div  [innerHTML]="RecommendedTests.Description"></div>
```

By the above code snippet, I am able to get the anchor tag, but the click event is not getting fired. I think it is because of XSS sanitization issue, but there is no proper solution related to XSS sanitization and binding click event could be found.

Is there any security concern occurred if I achieve this using DataSanitization for binding such things?

can someone help me out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

export class AppComponent {

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    Window["AppComponent"] = this;
  }


  this.RecommendedTests.Description = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<a onClick="Window.AppComponent.showModel()">'
      + this.RecommendedTests[i].Description  + '</a>')


  showModel() {
    alert("ok")
  }
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jii7hq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: @adrita.Thanks..But I tried this solution but it didn't work. anchor tag formed by this but click event still missing.

Comment: @Mr.Roshan Made some changes and added demo. Please check

Comment: Replace (click) with onClick

Comment: Thanks. I am getting SafeValue must use [property]=binding: error on my Front end.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue and share stackbiltz

Comment: I am storing my dynamically created anchor element in the array (as there will be multiple anchors). I am assigning this array to inner HTML due to same it's not populating the result

Comment: I can't help if you don't share the complete code. You can fork my demo and modify it and share

Answer (score 0):

this.RecommendedTests.Description =  `<a (click)="showModel()"> 
  +this.RecommendedTests[i].Description + </a>` ;
Try this in your code,i think it is work